# how to create a WAN (Wide Area Network)?

Tags: networking, wan, dial-up

assume we have a company with 5 branches that are not in same city of a country. We want to connect this branches to each other via a WAN without connecting to the internet. Is it possible to transfer data through a dial-up  connection? Is it possible to create a peer-to-peer connection through a phone line? If yes, what technologies(software or hardware) needed? I need some advices to understand WAN networking.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can setup a WAN and transfer data through a dial-up connection with modems at both end-points, all you need are modems and working phone lines, but paying per minute charges may make it prohibitive to maintain an always-on WAN connection via dial-ip.

You can also setup a WAN through a carrier-provided private network that does not connect to the internet, which would provide larger bandwidth options than dial-up.

So depending on your long-distance rate per minute for a phone connection (as your branches are in different cities), as well as your bandwidth requirement, you can determine if it makes more sense to utilize dial-up or to acquire a carrier-provided WAN over broadband circuits.